# How to update choice field options with a feature upgrade?

Tags: deployment, content-type, feature, field-definition, feature-upgrade

I created a feature with a field definition with choices. These choices are bound to language dependent resources  using the `$Resources:file:key` system. Resource files are included.

As the feature is activated the field is added to the site fields. All document libraries that use the content type have all the new field with the choices.
The subwebs (in different languages) have the field too - with the same options in their language.

**So far so good** - now the problem: I need to add new choices to the field. And that's where I got stuck. I tried several things like deactivating and activating the feature. I tried to remove the FieldLinks from the content-type and adding them back. I even tried to remove the field from the site completly. Nothing worked.

Of course I could read out the site field choices and add them to all document library fields. But this would overwrite choices language in the subwebs with the root-web language choices.

Is there a (good) way to update field options (add one or two) without losing the translations and without introducing a new location to maintain the choices in?

#### Update

I tried `DisplaceOnUpgrade="true"` in the Field definition. That updated the site field, but not the existing document library field.

Answer (score 2):

Could you add your field manifest?

Also, what does the feature receiver do?

Are you using sp2010or sp2007?

I havent tried with choice fields, but setting DisplaceOnUpgrade="true" instead of owerwrite="true" for field declaration helps upgrading existing fields.

Comment: Hi, I removed the reciever, tried the DisplaceOnUpgrade and did some experiments - still not working. (Please see the question for recent status updates.) - Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Have you tried manually changing the site columns using the GUI and selecting to push the change through to relevant list content types? In SP 2010 the situation is much better for this, as you can declare feature upgrades for site columns and select to push those changes through declaratively. If you want to do this in code, i would advice you to read my post on SO regarding some of the ways of doing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446451/sharepoint-what-happens-to-lists-based-on-content-type-when-content-type-is-upda/455962#455962